# How to allow selection for DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have this DataGridComboBoxColumn:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="OtherComboboxCol"
                        Header="Other"
                        SortMemberPath="Other" 
                        IsReadOnly="False"
                        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Other}"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Other, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding TripOtherStringList, Source={StaticResource StringProvider}"
                        Width="100">
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

My problem is that for some reason, I am unable to actually select a choice in a drop-down menu as a combobox should.  When I click on a cell in the column, nothing happens.  There does not seem to be a way to select any of the choices in TripOtherStringList.  There's not even a dropdown arrow for the combobox and it just looks like a TextBlock.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your DataGrid set to ReadOnly or IsEnabled = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the ComboBox all the time , create a template column. Read more [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/64f36ca4-bde9-4f32-8260-2b84e53bd8ca/wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-problem?forum=wpf).

Bottom line : For comboboxes, always use a template column.